# UICollectionView duplicates cells when returning from another view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I have been working on a weather app and been using UICollectionView to display weather data.

Whenever I open another view controller and return back to the UICollectionView's View controller, I get duplicate cells.

Here is the code. 
I use Alamofire to make api requests, append the json result to a local string and then assign it to the cell's text labels.

```
    class VaanizhaiViewController: UICollectionViewController {


    // MARK: - flow layout

    let columns : CGFloat = 2.0
    let inset : CGFloat = 3.0
    let spacing : CGFloat = 3.0
    let lineSpacing : CGFloat = 3.0
    var isRandom : Bool = false

    // MARK: - Variables
    var apiKey: String = "55742b737e883a939913f2c90ee11ec0"
    var country : String = ""
    var zipCode : String = ""
    var json : JSON = JSON.null
    var cityNames: [String] = []
    var temperature: [Int] = []
    var weather: [String] = []

    // MARK: - Actions


    // MARK: - view did load
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let layout = BouncyLayout()
        self.collectionView?.setCollectionViewLayout(layout, animated: true)
        self.collectionView?.reloadData()

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        for i in 0...zip.count-1{
            parseURL(zipCode: "\(zip[i])", country: "us")
        }

    }


    // MARK: - Functions

    func parseURL(zipCode: String, country: String){

        let url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=\(zipCode),\(country)&APPID=\(apiKey)&units=metric"
        requestWeatherData(link: url)
    }

    func requestWeatherData(link: String){
        Alamofire.request(link).responseJSON{ response in
            if let value = response.result.value{
                self.json = JSON(value)
                self.cityNames.append(self.json["name"].string!)
                let cTemp = ((self.json["main"]["temp"].double)!)
                self.temperature.append(Int(cTemp))
                let cWeather = self.json["weather"][0]["main"].string!
                self.weather.append(cWeather)
                self.collectionView?.reloadData()

            }
        }

    }




    // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return self.cityNames.count

    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "weatherCell", for: indexPath) as! WeatherViewCell

        if !self.cityNames.isEmpty {


        cell.cityLabel.text = self.cityNames[indexPath.row]
        cell.tempLabel.text = String (self.temperature[indexPath.row])
        cell.weatherLabel.text = self.weather[indexPath.row]
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown
    }

        return cell


   }
// MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

extension VaanizhaiViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let width = Int ((CGFloat(collectionView.frame.width) / columns) - (inset + spacing))
        return CGSize(width: width, height: width)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: CGFloat(inset), left: CGFloat(inset), bottom: CGFloat(inset), right: CGFloat(inset))
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return spacing
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return lineSpacing
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your viewDidAppear will be called every time you visit the view controller, and your viewDidLoad will only get called once, when it's created.

Therefore, you should probably switch your call to `self.collectionView?.reloadData()` to the viewDidAppear and your call to parseURL to the viewDidLoad

if you need to update your weather data (on a refresh, for example), then you need to restructure your requestWeatherData to stop appending to your arrays, and replace instead.